# Custom UIButton on TouchDown

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I'm interested in making a custom UIButton that has a custom event triggered when it's held down for X seconds.  I would like to have a border grow around the button as it's being held to indicate it's doing something and when it's a full border it's executed.

My questions is, what is the best way to implement this?  Should I be looking at UIViews or UIButtons?

I found this [tutorial series](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1), however it shows how to draw a button, but not create custom events that you can define when they would be triggered.

I've seen similar buttons in some apps before like SnapChat, I'm just wondering how it would be implemented.

Any help is appreciated,

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your UIButton lives in a UIView and the button is a subclass of UIView. When you press the button it should be connected to an IBAction. When the IBAction is called you'll need to start a timer to and start animating whatever change you need while the button is still held down. If the user releases the button before that timer completes you'll probably cancel whatever you were doing. If the user continues to hold the button down you'll continue animating. Keep in mind that the general way of calling an IBAction when a button is pressed is to do so when the user releases (lifts their finger). In your case you'll want to call the event as soon as the user taps the button and before it's raised. You'll also need to track if the user's finger is still inside the button or outside the button while your timer runs. If the user slides their finger away from the button you'll probably want to invalidate your timer and stop any button animation.

Comment: Thank you for the information xdeleon!  I was thinking it would be something along those lines, just wasn't sure if there was a more appropriate way to do it.  I would apply the animation to the UIButton then?  I'm not completely sure how I would do that animation, but just want to make sure I'm targeting the right thing.

Comment: Breakdown of work is: Track user pressed on button & while pressed run a timer. Once Timer completes fire off appropriate action (i.e. call a method to do something). Get that piece working first and tested. Once that works then you have to add code that will animate the button while the timer is running. I’m not sure what your animation does so I can’t add to that. I would google for “animate uibutton”. Also, if you are not that familiar with how some of the drawing code works consider checking out PaintCode to get more familiar with drawing/animating on iOS. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for the paintcodeapp.com link.  I'll definitely check it out.  I am looking to just animate a circular UIButton with a border circling around it.  Having the border complete would mean it's completed and some function will be called.